# Akkusativ in dem Satz »Mit mir als Praktikant (oder Praktikanten)«?

Tags: grammatical-case, grammaticality, accusative

ich bin mir unsicher, welcher der beiden Satzversionen richtig ist. Anders gesprochen, ob das Wort "Praktikant" im Akkusativ gesetzt werden muss. Hier die beiden möglichen Versionen:

> Mit mir als Praktikant können Sie....
>
> Mit mir als Praktikanten können Sie....

Für eine kurze Erklärung wäre ich dankbar.

Comment: Ich nehme an, du weißt, was du fragst. Weibliche Bewerber hätten dieses Problem nämlich nicht, da gäbe es nur _»Praktikantin«_ als Lösung.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kurzantwort:

- Normalerweise entspricht bei solchen *als*-Phrasen der Kasus der Konjunktionalphrase dem der Bezugsphrase. Das heißt: Weil *mir* im Dativ steht, müsste auch *Praktikant* im Dativ stehen: *mit mir als Praktikanten*.
- Aber: Substantive, die den Genitiv, Dativ und Akkusativ Singular eigentlich mit der Endung *-en* bilden, sind meist endungslos, wenn ihnen kein flektiertes
  Wort vorangeht: *mit mir als Praktikant*.

**Es sind also beide Varianten möglich.** Siehe auch *Duden*, Das Wörterbuch der sprachlichen Zweifelsfälle, 8. Auflage 2016 (Hervorhebung ergänzt):

> Schwach deklinierte maskuline Substantive **haben im Dativ und Akkusativ
> Singular eigentlich eine Flexionsendung, die aber unter bestimmten
> Bedingungen weggelassen wird**. Damit werden sie den stark deklinierten
> Substantiven angeglichen. *Als*-Gruppen mit
> diesen Substantiven erhalten häufig keine Kasusendung:
>
> mir *als Dozent*, ihm *als Held*, mit dem Sänger Meier *als Graf von Luxemburg*.
>
> Man kann
> davon ausgehen, dass *Dozent, Held, Graf* keine Nominative, sondern
> Dative ohne Flexionsendung sind. Genau genommen lassen sich aber ohne
> Kasusendung keine zuverlässigen Aussagen über einen Kasus treffen.
>
> Vollständige Formen sind erforderlich, wenn dem Substantiv ein
> flektiertes Wort vorausgeht:
>
> mir *als jüngerem Dozenten*, ihm *als großem
> Helden*, mit dem Sänger Meier *als verarmtem Grafen von Luxemburg*.

Answer (score 1):

Weder Nominativ noch Akkusativ. **Als** verbindet zwei Dinge derselben Sorte. Also muss auch der Fall übereinstimmen:

> Mit **dem** Schüler als **der** zuhörenden Person können Sie …

Die Präposition *mit* verlangt eine Dativergänzung, also muss auch nach **als** eine Dativergänzung folgen. Genauso mit den anderen Fällen.

> **Die** Sache als **solche** ist gelöst.
>
> An **den** Mann kann ich mich nicht als **einen** aus der Gruppe erinnern.

Es muss also

> als (dem) Praktikanten

heißen.

Comment: I thought it should it be in the nominative case because *als* here introduces a noun *Praktikant* which is in an apposition with *Sie* the subject in nominative case. It could be understood as *Sie (als Praktikant) können mit mir..*. Could this sentence be interpreted both ways?

Comment: No, it had to read *… Sie als Praktikant …* then. The case makes it clear which parts belong together, but the *als* comparision has a direction left to right. *Der Praktikant als Sie* is grammatical but *Sie* is the definition of *der Praktikant* then, which makes little sense.

Comment: *Der Praktikant war als Sie unterwegs?* – *The intern impersonated YOU?*